# JAXB MOXy marshalling and unmarshalling of JSON keys containing colons

Tags: json, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I am using Eclipse MOXy 2.6 and I have a very intractable problem during JSON marshalling and unmarshalling. I must produce and consume the following JSON object, respectively:

```
{
    "ssh::server::storeconfigs_enabled": true
}
```

Unfortunately, the key contains colons which collidates with the XML namespacing separator.

I use the following annotated domain class `SshOptions`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SshOptions {

    @XmlElement(name = "ssh::server::storeconfigs_enabled")
    private boolean storeConfigs;

    public boolean isStoreConfigs() {
        return storeConfigs;
    }

    public void setStoreConfigs(boolean storeConfigs) {
        this.storeConfigs = storeConfigs;
    }

}
```

I have used the following test code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SshOptions options = new SshOptions();
        options.setStoreConfigs(true);

        try {
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_NAMESPACE_SEPARATOR, '.');
            properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { SshOptions.class }, properties);

            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(options, output);
            System.out.println(output.toString());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The output is:

```
{
   "null" : true
}
```

Has anybody an idea how to marshall and unmarshal keys from and to JSON that have one or more colons in their names using Eclipse MOXy 2.6?